# Find an example of a complete bounded metric space which is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

I think the infinite dimensional sphere satisfies the following criteria.  However, I was hoping that someone could come up with a more elementary example.  Thanks.

Find an example of a complete bounded metric space which is not compact.

Comment: An infinite discrete space.

Comment: @David: That's a great example.

Comment: does a set {0,1 ,1/2,1/3....} with usual metric count?

Comment: @JamesWang. It's  compact.

Comment: As you can see by the A by Ittay Weiss, "bounded" is not a topological property: We cannot declare a subset of  a metric space to be unbounded  by only looking at the topology.

Answer (score 9):

Other than discrete spaces, you can take the following general approach. Take any non-compact metric space which is complete. To turn it into a bounded metric space without changing its non-compactness nor its completeness, just change the metric to $\min\{d(-,-),1\}$. So, for instance, $\mathbb R$ is complete, not compact, nor bounded (with the usual metric). After truncating the metric as above you get $\mathbb R$ with a metric such that it is bounded, is complete, but not compact. This little trick shows why in the context of a metric the concept of total boundedness is more useful than boundedness.

Comment: A variant is $e(x,y)=d(x,y)(1+d(x,y)\,)^{-1},$ which induces the same topology. as $d$. If $d$ is complete then so is $e,$ and if $d$ is unbounded then $e$ does not attain  its $lub$  (which is $1$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In a Banach space the closed unit ball is compact if and only if the dimension is finite; but a closed subset of a complete metric space is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "simple" example, then I can't think of anything different than a subset of a Banach space. Being complete means being close (since the whole space is complete), and for a closed bounded subset of a vector space to be non-compact, you have to be in an infinite dimensional vector space.